# Execution stucks on Channel.send

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

I have a suspend kotlin function which should get the first value from a flow and return it. However it stucks on ch.send(st)

```kotlin
    private suspend fun readSensorTemperature(): Double {
        val ch = Channel<Double>()

        val job = coroutineScope {
            launch {
                myFlow.collect { st ->
                    ch.send(st)
                }
            }
        }

        val res = ch.receive()
        job.cancel()

        return res
    }
```

Why my code does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to do this? A simpler way to get the first value from a flow is with `myFlow.first()`.

The reason your current code is suspending indefinitely is that the call to `coroutineScope` will suspend until all of its child coroutines have completed.

Because you call `collect` inside the `coroutineScope`, the `coroutineScope` cannot complete until the flow collection has completed. That means your code will never reach the calls to `receive` and `cancel` which would allow the flow collection to proceed and then be terminated.

A solution would be to move the `receive` and `cancel` calls inside the `coroutineScope`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatlly `first` does not work for me. I am reading data from flow (which actually provides data from a ble device) and calling `first` stucks my ble device for some reason. However when I call `collect` I can read the data from device fine. If I put `receive` inside `coroutineScope` I cannot return the value from the suspend function. So basically what I need is to wait until there appears a value in the flow and I can work with it. How can I do this in my coroutine?

Comment: @Solvek `first()` is doing exactly this - it waits for the first item and then returns. If it doesn't work for you then I guess your problem is somewhere else. Your current code is basically a convoluted way of doing `first()` and it should have similar properties when implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Such code seems to be working for me

```
suspend fun readSensorTemperature(): Double {
    var res: Double = -1.0

    val job = coroutineScope {
        launch {
            sensorTemperature.collect { st ->
                Log.d("ST", "Sensor temperature: $st")
                res = st
                cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    job.join()
    return res
}
```

Comment: Why in the question you collect from `myFlow` and here you collect from `sensorTemperature`? Is it the same flow, only renamed for posting?

Comment: It is the same.